# Define a custom template loader for FreeMarker with Spring

Tags: spring, exception, configuration, freemarker

I'm trying to use FreeMarker to create html for sending an email using Spring.  I do not want to access the templates from files, but rather get it from db (Mongo, but any db would be the same).
My current configuration is as follows:

```
<!-- freemarker config -->
<bean id="freemarkerConfiguration" class="org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean">
   <property name="preTemplateLoaders">
       <list>
           <ref bean="databaseTemplateLoader"/>
       </list>
   </property>
</bean>
<bean name="databaseTemplateLoader" class="com.myapp.service.MongoDBToFreeMarkerTemplateLoader"/>
```

When I autowire the Configuration object I get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [freemarker.template.Configuration] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.
```

I use the following code to Autowire:

```
@Autowired
Configuration freeMarkerTemplateEngine;
```

Without dependency injection (i.e. when using "new Configuration()" and manually setting the custom loader), it works fine, but obviously I want to stick to DI here.

Is there anything else I need to define in order to do this?  I've followed [this blog](http://nurkiewicz.blogspot.co.il/2010/01/writing-custom-freemarker-template.html) and it didn't say anything else is needed.

Comment: What requires a `Configuration` via auto-wiring here?

Comment: In order to use the template engine I need access to its "Configuration" object, so I can then call freeMarkerTemplateEngine.getTemplate(templateName);

Comment: If there's a better way to do it, please share, I'm open to suggestions

Answer (score 1):

Well, I figured it out.

As it turns out, there were two problems here:

1. I put the factory bean configuration in spring-servlet.xml, next to
   the freemarkerViewResolver which probably made it available to the
   view resolver, but invisible to the rest of the application.  Moving
   this config to applicationcontext.xml was step one in solving this
   problem.
2. I had a Maven misconfiguration.  When I added FreeMarker to
   my POM.XML file, I did not set the scope.  The default scope is
   Compilation, which means that Configuration class was not available
   at runtime.  Adding runtime to the freemarker maven
   include fixed that one.

It now works!

Answer (score 0):

To be able to use Spring's tag lib with a custom template loader

```
<#import "spring.ftl" as spring />
```

you need to do the following (using Java configuration):

```
public FreeMarkerConfigurer getFreemarkerConfig(DBTemplateLoader dbTemplateLoader) throws IOException, TemplateException {

    FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean freeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean = new FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean();

    freeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean.setPreTemplateLoaders(new ClassTemplateLoader(FreeMarkerConfigurer.class, ""), dbTemplateLoader);

    FreeMarkerConfigurer result = new FreeMarkerConfigurer();

    result.setConfiguration(freeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean.createConfiguration());

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is because Spring cannot find the matching bean defined in your applicationContext.

Since you define freemarker configuration bean like this:

```
<!-- freemarker config -->
<bean id="freemarkerConfiguration" class="org.springframework.ui.freemarker.FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean">
<property name="preTemplateLoaders">
   <list>
       <ref bean="databaseTemplateLoader"/>
   </list>
</property>
</bean>
<bean name="databaseTemplateLoader" class="com.myapp.service.MongoDBToFreeMarkerTemplateLoader"/>
```

Then in your code, you should inject bean with the name freemarkerConfiguration as below:

```
@Autowired
FreeMarkerConfigurationFactoryBean freemarkerConfiguration;
```